# XSLT - Own/Custom Tags (for Styling)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i want to specify own Tags like:  for my XSL Files because i have many redundant Blocks for styling:

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="1cm" color="#424242"> ... </fo:block>
```

So what i want is to take this `<fo:block>` element and put it in an much shorter Tag, so that i dont need to write this again and again and have only one simple Tag for this.

I googled now for hours and can't find a solution or someone who say "Impossible".

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Are you seeking a way to avoid repeating this while making your XSLT, or are you seeking a way to actually define an alias in your xsl-fo?

Comment: I would say i'm looking for a way to create an (short) alias for that, so that a Tag like <headline> would represent the <fo:block ...> element

Comment: So are you writing out this document by hand, or are you building it up using XSLT (or something else)?

Comment: I'm using apache FOP with Java to build a PDF Document, so yes its xslt (if i didn't got something wrong)

Comment: So can you show us some of your XSLT that uses these elements? We can try to show you how to reduce the duplication.

Comment: I have many different templates and in nearly all of them i have headlines which all have the same style:

<fo:block font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="1cm" color="#424242">Headline</fo:block>

Comment: Could you show us at least one of them?

Comment: Sorry but that are over 400 Lines which i have to edit manually in the post editor because stackoverflow doesnt let me post it like it is (because of tabs)

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You can select all the code and press Ctrl+K to mark it as code and it will show up as code. I also only asked to see a relevant portion of your XSLT, not all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that is fairly close to what you want is to use an [xsl:attribute-set](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets)

Example:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="headline">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-bottom" select="'1cm'"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="color" select="'#424242'"/>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="headline">...</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

*Note: If you're using XSLT 1.0, you can't use `select` in `xsl:attribute`.*

Answer (score 0):

Edit: removed my initial incorrect assumption

You can include one XSLT into another. So if you have many templates that share some definitions, put all of the shared definitions into one shared template and use `<xsl:include>` to refer to the shared template. 
[Information on `include`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_include.asp)

Comment: Hmm dont know if you got me wrong or i wrote a bit weird :D

I have something like this:

<fo:block font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="1cm" color="#424242">Some text...</fo:block>

But instead of writing the whole fo:block part again and again i want to "wrap" it into an simple tag so that i can write:

<headline>Some text...</headline>

Answer (score 0):

XSLT allows you to collect an XML document as a tree and then use that tree as your current context. In other words, you can do your own pre-processing of the "macros" you are using.

I suggest you create a namespace for your macros, making the debugging process easier.